# TSQL Aggregate function to produce a yes or no flag

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I will attempt to explain my problem using a similar but simpler problem. Let's say that I'm writing software for a library, which has a table of `Patron`s and `Book`s. In addition, it has a `CheckOuts` table which associates `Patron`s to any `Book`s (1 per row) that they have checked out.

I'm using MSSQL 2005 and need to build a view or stored procedure that contains two columns, `PatronID` and `HasBook`, which needs to be dynamically generated: 1 if the patron has one or more book checked out, and 0 otherwise.

Here is my first attempt at writing a query to do this:

```
SELECT PatronID, MIN((SELECT 1, COUNT(BookID) FROM CheckOuts WHERE CheckOuts.PatronID = Patrons.PatronID)) AS HasBook
            FROM Patrons
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function
>   on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

I'm a very new SQL user, so if that query makes you cringe, I would sincerely appreciate any advice you would like to give. I'm very interested in the "right" way to do this.

Comment: If a book is not checked out, the `CheckOuts` table will have no rows for a matching `Book`, right? And likewise, if a patron has no books, the `CheckOuts` table will have no matching `Patron`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you just want to know if the PatronId has any checkout, you can do the following:

```
SELECT PatronID, CASE WHEN B.PatronId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasBook
FROM Patrons A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PatronId FROM CheckOuts GROUP BY PatronId) B
ON A.PatronId = B.PatronId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.PatronID, CASE b.PatronID WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM Patrons a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patrons b ON b.PatronID = a.PatronID AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CheckOuts c WHERE c.PatronID = b.PatronID)
```

EDIT: Lamak's solution, using the derived table, may be better than mine. His is probably faster.